# How to update my Teams app already deployed in Azure?

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I wanted to know what the procedure was for updating the Teams application developed with the Microsoft Teams Toolkit once it's deployed in Azure. Indeed, if we click on Deploy or Provision, no build folder is created, it is only created the first time and the command npm run build does not work. What should I do?
Thank you in advance.

I tried to proven and deploy the app again, and run rpm run build command

Comment: Could you please follow the steps which is mentioned in below document for updating the Teams Toolkit app:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/toolkit-v4/aad-manifest-customization-v4

Answer (score 0):

Could you please follow the below steps for updating the Teams Toolkit app:

You can customize Azure AD manifest template to update Azure AD application.

1. Open aad.template.json in your project.
2. Update the template directly or reference values from another file.
   Following are the customization scenarios:

   ```
   Add an application permission

   Pre-authorize a client application

   Update redirect URL for authentication response
   ```
3. Deploy Azure AD application changes for local environment
4. Deploy Azure AD application changes for remote environment

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/toolkit-v4/aad-manifest-customization-v4#customize-azure-ad-manifest-template

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate on the scenario, the type of update you need, and what app you are building. Also, include the version details of the team's toolkit and packages.

I have been working on this for over a year. I can help you for sure.

For now, if you want to release a new version in-store, goto to publishing options.
If you want to manually run a build, navigate to the app directory and in the terminal run `npm run build`.
It's better to use the team's toolkit only, it generally updates the file in the build folder not delete and create again as some of the frameworks out there

When you click on `Deploy`,

- it builds your app
- upload to the cloud

If you have it published and you want to update it then,

- update your version number in the manifest.
- click on `Publish`

*Note*: It will not be published unless you update the version number as it will not be considered as an update.

If it is not an answer to your question, consider providing more details.